# How to resize the iframe in cross domain url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Can any body tell I am trying to load url in iframe onload function is .I want to display iframe without scroll bar and adjust to its content but parent page will scroll depend on the content can anybody tell How to resize the iframe in cross domain url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to resize the iframe based on its content, you cann use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send the current iframe height to its parent.

The page that is included inside the iFrame needs to send its current height using postMessage to the including page.
The including page has to listen on that message and change the height of the iframe accordingly.

The code in the included page could look something like this:

```
function getBottom() {
    var max = jQuery("body").height();
    //Your additional calculations go here
    return max;
}

function updateHeight() {
    sendHeightToParent();
    setTimeout(updateHeight, 500);
}

function sendHeightToParent() {
    var messageObject = {
        "type":"size",
        "version":"1.0.0",
        "params":{
            "height": getBottom()
        }
    };

    //YOURTARGET is the target page if known. Otherwise use "*"
    parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(messageObject), "YOURTARGET");
}

//Only possible if html5 post message is available
if (typeof parent.postMessage == 'function') {
    jQuery().ready(function() {
        sendHeightToParent();
        setTimeout(updateHeight, 500);
    });
}
```

The parent then listens on the event and updates the iframe accordingly:

```
//Only possible if html5 post message is available
if (typeof parent.postMessage == 'function') {
    window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
        obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (obj.type == 'size') {
            myFrame = document.getElementById('YouIFrameId');
            myFrame.stye.height = obj.params.height + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from body tag which method i need to call  or  need to call from iframe .can you update the code

Comment: In the page that includes the iframe you add the second code.
In the included page you add the first code.

Comment: .I have added iframe in same page in  index.jsp